# selinuxをenforcingにするとmysqlで登録できません（symfony3）

Tags: mysql, symfony2, mariadb, doctrine2, selinux

お世話になります。

あるSymfony入門書のコードを実践してみているのですが、selinuxをenforcingにするとmysqlでレコードを登録できずに行き詰まっていますので、お力を貸していただけないでしょうか？

エラーメッセージは、以下の通りです。
An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Permission denied

環境は、以下の通りです。
CentOS7 php7 MariaDB Symfony3.04

ちなみに・・・
selinux をPermissive にすると レコードの登録は可能です。

また、以前、同じサーバで入門サイト参考にして作成したものは、レコードの登録は可能です。
こちらは selinuxをenforcing にしても登録可能です。

以上のことから、今、実践している分の selinux の設定が間違えているのかと思っているのですが、良く分かりません。

symfony のエラー部分を抜粋すると
CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException: "An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Permission denied" at /home/www/classic-symfony/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 103

ですが、AbstractMySQLDriver.php は
system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 です。

以上、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

Enforcing でうまくいっているサーバーと `getsebool -a` に違いはないでしょうか。
たとえば、`setsebool httpd_can_network_connect_db on` で許可を与えるとどうでしょうか。

/var/log/audit/audit.log に SELinux のポリシーに違反したもの("avc:  denied") が記録されていますので、それを調べると何かわかるかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
setsebool httpd_can_network_connect_db on でうまくいきました。
getsebool -a は同じサーバですので違いはありません。
/var/log/audit/audit.log には一度削除後再度insert文を発行したのですが何も記録されませんでした。

Comment: なるほどですね。今、symfonyのdatabaseの設定を確認しました。うまくいっている方は、databasehost が localhost、うまくいかない方は、127.0.0.1 でした。違いは何か？が気になっていたので、解決しました。ありがとうございました。